# Choosing divisor in division method of hashing

Tags: data-structures, hash, language-agnostic

According to CLRS

> A prime not too close to an exact power of 2 is often a good choice for m

while calculating hash values through the division method, where the hash function is:

```
h(k) = k mod m
```

While it makes sense to not choose m as a power of 2, how is the distance of m from an exact power of 2 going to affect the hashing?

Comment: It's worth experimenting to see collision rates for various values of `m`. I think you'll uncover the reasoning pretty quickly.

Comment: Possibly related? "*As Exercise 11.3-3 asks you to show, choosing m = 2^p-1 when k is a character string interpreted in radix 2^p may be a poor choice, because permuting the characters of k does not change its hash value.*"